# Call a function defined in a fragment, from the main activity that required a view

Tags: android, view, fragment

I have a function in a fragment `(Frag_Lista)` that changes its cardView dynamically using the output of a query.
The first time i call it from that fragment and it works. The second time i would call it from the `main activity`, but i can't set correctly the second parameter, the `view`.

Frag_Lista

```
public void function_in_fragment() {
//some code
Context context = getActivity();
DBhelper database = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getDatabase();
Cursor cursor=database.ottieni_tutto();
genera_lista(cursor,getView());
```

}

```
public void genera_lista(Cursor cursor, View v) {
    list.clear();
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                //Log.d(TAG,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COL_NOME)));
                String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COL_NOME));
                String tipo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COL_TIPO));
                String difficolta = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COL_DIFFICOLTA));
                String immagine = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COL_IMMAGINE));
                Food_Card food_card = new Food_Card(immagine, nome, tipo, difficolta);
                list.add(food_card);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        else Log.d(TAG,"Cursor vuoto");
    }
    else Log.d(TAG,"Cursor nullo");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter=new food_adapter(getActivity(),list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

MainActivity

```
public void function_in_mainActivity(String[] parametri) {
Cursor cursor=database.query_filtri(parametri);
Frag_Lista nothing=new Frag_Lista();
View v= ?
nothing.genera_lista(cursor,v);
```

}

How can i pass correctly the current view?

Frag_Lista

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_lista, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return(v);
}
```

Comment: You are not using the View paramter in your method signature at all. Why do you need it?

Comment: @MuratK. Wrong code: edit

Comment: How does your `onCreateView` method look like?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, could you please explain?

Comment: @MuratK. i add it.

Comment: @Egor i would like to modify my CardView from main activity. The cardView is in a fragment and the function that i use to change it is in that fragment. I need the view to use RecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); because if i use getView() in this case it will be null: so i need to pass it from MainActivity and i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onCreateView` like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_lista, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return(v);
}
```

Crate a field inside your `Fragment` for `recyclerView`.

Now you always have a reference to the `RecyclerView` and don't need to pass it as a argument to the method.

```
public void genera_lista(Cursor cursor)
```

Comment: so, should i delete in genera_lista() recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);?

Comment: I removed recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); from the function, but doing that, when i call from the main activity that function, recyclerView is null